# I am creating a sample website. How do I check how it looks on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

I have not launched the website yet. All the mobile testing websites I have found on the internet are asking for my URL. Is there any way to test a website that has not been launched yet?

Comment: You can resize the browser, or use the developer's tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Chrome's responsive mode:

- Go to DevTools (`Ctrl+Shift+I`)
- Click the phone/tablet icon in topbar (2nd from the left) or `Ctrl+Shift+M`

Then you can resize website or select sample device from menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it on more number of mobile simulators with chrome **Device Toolbar** that is inside **Developer Tools**. it looks great with many inbuild mobile device simulators. (That is second left mobile like icon on the inspect element).

Once you click on the icon you can switch through devices using the top device selector. You can even change width and height of the device and zoom it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You could try multiple extensions from chrome web store such as 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-web-design-tes/objclahbaimlfnbjdeobicmmlnbhamkg?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon if you are using chrome. Type "responsive" in search and you will get various extensions. You can also do ctrl+shift+m.

If using firefox you can do Ctrl+shift+m and you can view your website in responsive mode.

Also you can try resizing the browser as a third alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome then go through [this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). For Interner Explorer try [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Google Chrome and then inspect by right clicking on your webpage. Click on Responsive icon in the menu bar (shown in  attached image) and adjust screen size.

You need to write MEDIA QUERIES for making your page responsive for different screen sizes.

[image: ATTACHED IMAGE]

Answer (score 0):

use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). It will expose the local/dev servers using their services. This command line tool will give you a resolvable url.

To use

```
$ ngrok http 80
```

will expose the web server running on port 80.

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                                                                                                                                     
(Ctrl+C to quit)

Session Status                online
Version                       2.2.4
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://dbg6f82d.ngrok.io -> localhost:80

Forwarding                    https://dbf8f82d.ngrok.io -> localhost:80
```

This will be accessible across the internet.